# How to get the correct newIndex when using pagination in Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have implemented pagination according to the docs. I'm using this code in my project:

```
override fun onEvent(querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot?, e: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
    if (e != null) return

    for (documentChange in querySnapshot!!.documentChanges) {
        value = when (documentChange.type) {
            Type.ADDED -> {
                Log.d("TAG", "oldIndex:" + documentChange.oldIndex + "/" + "newIndex:" + documentChange.newIndex)
            }
            Type.MODIFIED -> {
                Log.d("TAG", "oldIndex:" + documentChange.oldIndex + "/" + "newIndex:" + documentChange.newIndex)
            }
            Type.REMOVED -> {
                Log.d("TAG", "oldIndex:" + documentChange.oldIndex + "/" + "newIndex:" + documentChange.newIndex)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm using this query to get the first 4 users:

```
var query: Query = db.collection("users")
    .orderBy("name", DESCENDING)
    .limit(4)
```

I get:

```
A/oldIndex:-1/newIndex:0
B/oldIndex:-1/newIndex:1
C/oldIndex:-1/newIndex:2
D/oldIndex:-1/newIndex:3
```

Which is correct, since all the users are new and have the oldIndex equal to -1. The newIndex is incremented from 0 to 3 which is also correct. However, when I'm using this Query:

```
var secondQuery: Query = db.collection("users")
    .orderBy("name", DESCENDING)
    .startAfter(lastVisibleUser)
    .limit(4)
```

To get the next 4 users, I get:

```
E/oldIndex:-1/newIndex:0
F/oldIndex:-1/newIndex:1
G/oldIndex:-1/newIndex:2
H/oldIndex:-1/newIndex:3
```

Where the name of the users is correct, the oldIndex is again correct, but the newIndex starts from 0 and **not** from 4 as it should be. How can I get the correct newIndex, second time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indexes that you get for snapshots are compared to the previous snapshot of **the same listener**. Since you fire a new query, it is a new listener, and so all indexes are based on an empty previous state.

To see how indexes **do** work, attach a permanent listener to the query, then change the name of one of the users in the first query so that it changes its location in the results. You'll see the previous and new index for all users be updated based on the previous snapshot and the new state.

Comment: [It seems that there is no "permanent listener"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63070004/how-to-attach-a-permanent-listener-to-a-firestore-query/63083920#63083920), right?

Comment: In order to get the indexes you are trying to use here, you'll have to use a single listener. If you're trying to implement pagination, you'll need multiple listeners, but in that case you can't use the indexes - as they'll be calculated separate for each listener.